# R installation on AIX 7.2 Package installation missing modules

Tags: r, oracle, aix

Installed a 3.2.0 distribution of R (Oracle R) on an AIX 7.2 box (with supposedly all the required dependencies.)

When I try to install a package (regardless of the package but data.table would be the first one), the following error shows up:

```html
        /systemr/port/AIX/comp/oraxlc.shx -F/systemr/port/AIX/comp/xlc.cfg -I/usr/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/systemr/port/AIX/include -I/opt/freeware/include -I/usr/linux/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lpp/X11/include/X11 -I/systemr/port/AIX/include/cairo -I/systemr/port/AIX/lib/pixman      -O -qstrict -qnoldbl128  -c chron_strs.c -o chron_strs.o
/systemr/port/AIX/comp/oraxlc.shx: not found

make: The error code from the last command is 1.


Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'chron'
* removing '/usr/lib/R/library/chron'
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C"
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C"
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C"
ERROR: dependency 'chron' is not available for package 'data.table'
* removing '/usr/lib/R/library/data.table'

The downloaded source packages are in
        '/tmp/RtmpfuNMaa/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/modules//R_X11.so':
  Could not load module /usr/lib/libX11.a(shr_64.o).
        Dependent module libiconv.a(shr4_64.o) could not be loaded.
        Member shr4_64.o is not found in archive
Could not load module /usr/lib/R/modules//R_X11.so.
        Dependent module /usr/lib/libX11.a(shr_64.o) could not be loaded.
2: In install.packages("data.table") :
  installation of package 'chron' had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("data.table") :
  installation of package 'data.table' had non-zero exit status
```

Now, I have seen previous posts suggesting creating a symlink between oraxlc.shx and oraxlc in the systemr folder but I can't seem to find this folder for the life of me.

The "member shr4_64.o is not found in archive), preventing libiconv.a from loading is also out standing as an error.

Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Might be related: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html#Q0009

Comment: Try to find out which `libiconv.a` is used, and check its content.